# SQL Trigger - Check for string

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to run a trigger whenever a new row is inserted into lets say `shipping_rate`, and it will check column `company` within that row for a certain string. If that certain string is is there, I then want to perform an equation on column `cost` to change the current number. Is this feasible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible as trigger can do essentially anything to the database that a normal query could. You can read up on how to do that in [official manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).